# Why does my AP get refilled in AC: Project Legacy?

Tags: assassins-creed-project-legacy

I've just started playing Assassin's Creed: Project Legacy and something has me mystified. I've figured out that the following gain me AP:

1. Having the game open for 2 minutes (+1)
2. Increasing maximum AP by 1 (+1)
3. Increasing Security Level (refill)

However, sometimes when I log on I find my AP has completely refilled, and I don't know why. Am I supposed to get a full load of AP every day? Or is something not realising I've closed the game, and 1. above is clocking up overnight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I think AP goes up by 1 every two minutes whether or not the game is open.

However, my mobile browser keeps the flash application open overnight without allowing it to run (i.e. the in-game counter doesn't tick down), and so when I reopen the page later I have the same AP. If I completely refresh the page, my AP increases properly.